# How can I use cube (3) or square (2) by CDO to calculate values?

Tags: cdo-climate

How can use cube (3) or square (2) by CDO to calculate values?

I do not understand how I can use cube (3) or square (2) by CDO to calculate wind density.
Please see the following equation.
We have data (m/s) in the NC file. --> infile.nc

Wind density (WD) =  0.6125*v^3[image]

Comment: Please use text for your question (images cannot be copied).
Also please check the tags: what does email have to do with this?

Comment: And .net and cdo.message for that matter. These are questions that are easily answered by reading the excellent CDO user guide. You need to take the power of something and multiply it. The user guide explains quite clearly how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

On a spoon:

```
cdo mulc,0.6125 -mul v.nc -mul v.nc v.nc windden.nc
```

To spell it out,

```
-mul v.nc v.nc
```

multiplies v by v,

and then

```
-mul v.nc
```

multiplies that by v to give the cube...

Alternatively, and slightly more concisely, you can use the square function `sqr`:

```
cdo mulc,0.6125 -mul v.nc -sqr v.nc windden.nc
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was flagged as not providing an answer. Any regular CDO user will quickly see that it solves the problem